# Google Drive API：How to download files from google drive？

Tags: python, google-drive-api

```
access_token = ''
import json
r = session.request('get', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?access_token=%s' % access_token)
response_text = str(r.content, encoding='utf-8')
files_list = json.loads(response_text).get('files')
files_id_list = []
for item in files_list:
    files_id_list.append(item.get('id'))

for item in files_id_list:
    file_r = session.request('get', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%s?alt=media&access_token=%s' % (item, access_token))
    print(file_r.content)
```

I use the above code and Google shows：
We're sorry ...
... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
I do n’t know if this method ca n’t be downloaded originally, or where is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to enable some permissions in google for it work via code. I faced similar problems when doing oauth login few years back .

Comment: I consulted the documentation and did not see the specified authentication, but instead used access_token.I continue to query the document.

Comment: Hello, if you solved the issue, please put your solution as an answer, so other can see how to fix it.

Comment: can you try putting sleep between calls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access_token should not be placed in the request body,We should put access_token in the header.Can try on this site [oauthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is you are requesting the data in a Loop.
causes so many requests to Google's server.

And hence the error
We're sorry ... ... but your computer or network may be **sending automated queries**